# Onde ficam os arquivos dos projetos desenvolvidos no Android Studio no Linux?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um App para Android usando o Android Studio, porém como ainda não publiquei, é costume meu fazer um backup no final do dia de trabalho. Estou usando o Linux e não estou encontrando onde ficam os arquivos dos projetos para eu fazer esse backup. Onde ficam exatamente esses arquivos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O topo do título da barra do Android Studio mostra o nome completo do path do diretório onde você está salvando o seu projeto.

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Tem razão Yan. Não me atentei a esse detalhe, pois uso em Full Screen. Obrigado.